# Styles from resources aren't used when UserControl is instantiated in other class

Tags: wpf, resources, styles

I create custom WPF Expander inherited from common Expander. I have a file with styles at path `MyAssembly/Theme/generic.xaml`. I can see that **styles are applied in designer but are not in running program**.

MyExpander.xaml:

```
<Expander x:Class="Path.To.MyExpander"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <Expander.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Theme/generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Expander.Resources>
    ...
```

generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    ...
```

code where I instanciate the expanders:

```
class Viewer
{
    private void GenerateExpanders()
    {
        this.Expanders.Children.Clear();
        foreach (...)
        {
            MyExpander ex = new MyExpander();
            ex.HeaderText.Text = "Sample";
            ex.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            ex.IsExpanded = true;
            this.Expanders.Children.Add(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

All three files are in one assembly but class Viewer is instantiated in another assembly. 
Is there something am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would see if there is any way to verify that Expander is actually able to access that ResourceDictionary file.  I have had several instances where Source="..." wire up properly Design Time but mysteriously break after compiling.  Also, is this WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: It's WPF. I add this info to question.

Comment: Are these styles actually theme-specific, or are they just standalone styles meant to be applied regardless of what theme the user has set? To help diagnose the problem, could you possibly copy these styles to a new XAML resource dictionary and reference that file instead in your MergedDictionaries section, just to see if they suddenly work when not applied as part of the theme?

Comment: This is not the recommended way of creating a custom WPF control.  If you want custom _functionality_: create MyExpander.cs, derived from Control and define MyExpander's template in Generic.xaml OR in another ResourceDictionary (to be merged into Generic.xaml).  If you want a different _look_: just create a new Style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had

```
<Style TargetType="Expander"
```

but it should be

```
<Style TargetType="MyExpander"
```

I didn't realise that it wasn't Expander anymore - it was MyExpander (`class MyExpander : Expander`)